# zip permission denied in batch script

Tags: windows, cmd, zip

I’m using zip.exe (2.31) on Windows Server 2012R2.
I have a large txt file and I want to zip it before transfer it through scp. Thus I will run

```
zip.exe -1 -m "%DIR%\%~n1.zip" %1
```

where %1 is the full path of my txt file.
But this script throw out

> zip warning: multiple disk information ignored

> zip.exe: found a preamble of 20464 bytes

> zip warning: name not matched: DIR_PATH\FILE.zip

> zip I/O error: Permissions denied

But if I directly type

```
zip.exe -1 -m DIR_PATH\FILE.zip FILE.txt
```

or

```
zip.exe -1 -m FILE.zip FILE.txt
```

in the `DIR_PATH` in cmd (this is exactly same to the line in my script, because I `echo` it from the script and copy to cmd to run directly), it would work fine.

So why there are errors only when I run this command in script?

Comment: Can you see the difference between, `“%DIR%\%~n1.zip”` and `"%DIR%\%~n1.zip"`? You have not provided sufficient information for your task, we do not know the value of `%DIR%` or how it was defined, nor do we know the exact path you passed to the script and how you did that. Also I'd suggest that you use `"%~1"` instead of `%1`.

Comment: @Compo actually they are the same. It can work when I copied the cmd from script and run in cmd directly.

Comment: No they are not! smart, _(curly)_, quotes and dumb, (straight), quotes, are not the same. You need to use the straight ones!

Comment: @Compo sorry for lack of sufficient info since I’m using phone to type this question. I have updated my question

Comment: You haven't provided the information I mentioned though, have you? I'm currently using a phone too, _although I fail to see how that is relevant to you providing information_.

Comment: The code in the question is using a LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (U\201D) and a RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (U\201D). The code needs to use QUOTATION MARK (U\0022).

Comment: @lit thanks lit. I believe this is caused by the keyboard of my phone, and the real code should already use the right quotation mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue might be caused by the compatibility of Windows server 2012R2.
After I changed the compatibility setting of the `zip.exe` to `Windows 7`, all problems were gone.